# What's the right way of setting up on CouchDB server and using PouchDB in production

Tags: couchdb, progressive-web-apps, production-environment, pouchdb

I'm new to CouchDB & PouchDB.

I'm looking to create an application with below items:

- ReactJS (Frontend framework with offline cache)
- CouchDB (Database)
- PouchDB (Offline/Online data synchonise)

**Setting up COUCHDB**

I've successfully set up CouchDB on a Linux server and am able to access CouchDB at `http://localhost:5984` and creating it via this SSH command `ssh -L5984:127.0.0.1:5984 user@{SERVERIP}`

**Simple PouchDB client side codes**

```
// local database, that lives in the browser's IndexedDB store
var localDB = new PouchDB('mylocaldb')

// remote CouchDB 
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/myremotedb')
```

**What about production?**

When it comes to production, my client side PouchDB code will still using this code?

```
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/myremotedb')
```

or should have replace the `localhost` to my actual domain name eg:

```
var remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://myproductionserver.com:5984/myremotedb')
```

But to my understanding, exposing CouchDB to public is very risky.
What's the right way of setting up on CouchDB & using PouchDB in production server? eg: access CouchDB from mobile, desktop devices.

Comment: Unless you're running CouchDB on the same device running PouchDB (i.e. on a mobile phone), using `localhost` won't work for obvious reasons. There is no alternative to exposing CouchDB publicly. Why do you believe this is risky?

Comment: I'm kinda confused on the approach of how PouchDB executing HTTP request to CouchDB, base on the document at (https://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html)

`var db = new PouchDB('todos');
var remoteCouch = 'http://user:pass@myname.example.com/todos';`

To my understanding it's not a good way to expose `user:pass` in public/client side correct if i'm building a PWA.

Comment: Your client needs to know the credentials to connect to CouchDB somehow.